# how to count data from mysql and then show it in javafx

Tags: mysql, javafx

My problem is that I want to apply the following two commands in JavaFX in order to get how many 1ones are in a named "party" column from a database named "conteo".

```
   sql ="select count(*) from conteo where party =1";

   ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
```

i used System.out.println(rs.getString("party")); to expect the correct number of 1ones in "party" column from "conteo" database and i get "the error column party do not exist", but actually it already exist!!!

```
   sql ="select count(*) from conteo where party =1";

   ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
```

I would like to print in command line "rs" using "System.out.println()"
My database address is correctly address it, because i already write data sucessfully in mysql databases using javafx, how can i properly print "rs" result in command line?, anyhelp is appreciated, thanks in advance, Omar Torres

Comment: "select count(*) `as party` from conteo where party =1" Currently, you are not selecting a column named party in your query. Either name you count as `party` or select a column that's named `party`

Comment: sql ="select count(*) from conteo where party =1"; already works in mysql and give me my answer correctly in mysql command line, "select count(*) as party from conteo where party =1" works in javafx?

Comment: ok, i will try it that, thank you in advance

Comment: The ResultSet only has whatever you select.

Comment: thank you very much, i solved my problem, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked...

> how can i properly print "rs" result

Do you mean something like this...

```
if (rs.next()) {
    int theCount = rs.getInt(1);
    System.out.println(theCount);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, thank you very much, your answer really help me, thank you

Comment: Then I suggest you mark my answer as the accepted answer. Simply click on the big √ (tick mark).

Answer (score 1):

You did not select the `party` column for the output. Since you're using a aggregate function, this shouldn't work in this case anyways. You'd need to use `GROUPING BY`+`HAVING` anyways.

It's much simpler to provide an alias for the value

```
sql ="SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM conteo WHERE party =1";
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql); 
if (rs.next()) {
    int i = rs.getInt("num");
    ...
}
```

or

```
sql ="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM conteo WHERE party =1";
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql); 
if (rs.next()) {
    int i = rs.getInt(1); // access first column in result
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i really solved my problem, thank  you